# Why am I unable to permanently enable 'edit mode' on a List when retrieving data from CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to create a permanently editable/selectable List that is populated with data from CoreData.. I can create a list with edit mode enabled if I use a Local array, but not when I pull from CoreData.... Rather confused by this.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Product.name, ascending: true)])
private var products: FetchedResults<Product>

@State var selectKeeper = Set<String>()


var body: some View {

    VStack{
        
        List(products, id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper) { product in
                HStack {
                    if let data = product.photo,
                       let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
                    }
                    VStack{
                        Text(product.name ?? "")
                        Text(product.desc ?? "")
                    }

                }
       
          Text(product.name ?? "")
        }.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))

       }
}
```

Comment: `…,id: \.self, selection: $selectKeeper)`, if id is `self` then shouldn’t `selectKeeper` be declared as `Set<Product>()`?

Comment: Correct, changing the selectKeeper value resolved this for me.